# Selenium: How do I get a text within a <td> tag and then click the Javascript link of it's sibling?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a list of forms that I need to edit one by one wherein I have to identify the form title first and then click the JavaScript link to open it's editing template.

In the sample code below, I need to identify the text `Another Custom Form (Mobile)` which is the form title and then click the `a href` link whose `onclick` value is `editProjectFormType`. It is the second sibling of form title. I am trying to perform this task in Python.

```html
<tr class="trbg2">
  <td width="10%" align="left" nowrap="nowrap">
    <div align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFormType" value="2192454$$rmymiK" checked="checked">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="10%" align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><img src="https://dmsak.qa.asite.com/images/dots.gif" width="6" height="15">!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ashish_test!!!!!!!!!!</td>
  <td width="10%" align="left">Custom forms</td>
  <td width="10%" align="center">ACFM</td>
  <td width="24%">Another Custom Form (Mobile)</td>
  <td width="20%">Custom</td>
  <td align="center" width="15%">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editProjectFormType('2192454$$rmymiK');">
      <img src="https://dmsak.qa.asite.com/images/i_editfgt.gif" width="16" height="20" border="0">
    </a>
  </td>
  <td align="center" width="15%">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="downloadFormTemplate('2192454$$rmymiK');">
      <img src="https://dmsak.qa.asite.com/images/f_dow_tmple.gif" width="22" height="22" border="0" alt="Click here to Download Template" title="Click here to Download Template">
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have used the following incomplete code so far and not sure what do I do next

```
button = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
for txt in button:
    if txt == "Another Custom Form (Mobile)":
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with jQuery if you want to perform the test in Python?

Comment: My mistake, I am new to this site and coding as well. jQuery came as a suggestion so I tagged it.

Comment: Please share your code as well which have you tried for this...

Comment: why not to just find an anchor tag with `onclick="editProjectFormType('2192454$$rmymiK');"` attribute and click on it?

Comment: @Andersson because I have more than one form to edit on different projects and the people who will provide me the list of those forms will only have the form names (like 'Another Custom Form (Mobile)' in this case).

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I have added the code that I am trying to use, it's incomplete and I am not even sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: If I suggest you a single line `xPath` where you can provide text `Another Custom Form (Mobile)` to identify their `following-sibling` and get that link as `//td[contains(text(),'Another Custom Form (Mobile)')]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@onclick, 'editProjectFormType')]`....then is this enough for you??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes I believe xpath would be the right way to do it.

Comment: Ok then I am converting it to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform click on `link` with following single `xPath` where you can provide text `Another Custom Form (Mobile)` to identify their `following-sibling` and get that `link` as as below :-

```
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Another Custom Form (Mobile)')]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@onclick, 'editProjectFormType')]")
link.click()
```

**Edited..**

Implement `WebDriverWait` to get the `element` as below :-

```
link = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),'Another Custom Form (Mobile)')]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@onclick, 'editProjectFormType')]"))) 
link.click()
```

**Note:-** if target `element` is inside a `frame`. you need to switch to that `frame` first as `browser.switch_to_frame("frame name or id")` then go to find the target `element` as above.

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh but this throws an error, could it be because the link is the second sibling after `<td width="20%">Custom</td>`?

Comment: No matter it's second or third....it just scan all the following-sibling...

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(text(),'Another Custom Form (Mobile)')]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@onclick, 'editProjectFormType')]"}`

Comment: Now it says `NameError: name 'EC' is not defined`

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC` import as like this..

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, it worked. I didn't know I had to switch frames to default every time I was switching frames in Python.

Comment: @Chandral you are welcome...Please accept the answer as well if it helped..:)

Comment: I did upvote this answer, but it says I need more rep points to make it a public upvote. It's because I am new to the site I guess.

Comment: @Chandral follow this link...http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work&ei=Oy8RGn_0&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=971&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1466519457&sig=AKOVD65rTFg7AWS__qw0_f12kNjoO4s0uQ

Comment: The first one  worked for me with some modification.
I have 3 buttons in single td, with other 4 td have texts. I have to click on specific button based on the one td value (e.g customer_name). Below is working the code.
`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//td[contains(text(),'" + customer_name + "')]/following-sibling::td/button[text()='Accept']"
            ).click()`

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by:

- 1. creating a class to represent a row in this table, say **"MyRow"**, which has method to interact with each column as a field in the class.
- 2. using Selenium to find all of the rows in the table, returning a list of instances of this class.
- 3. loop thru the list looking for the row that matches the target name :

  ```
  for (MyRow myRow : allRows) {
      if (myRow.name.equals("Another Custom Form (Mobile)")) {
          return myRow;
      }
  }
  ```
- 4. click on the link in the target row's column. `myRow.editProjectForm()`

Comment: Thanks for the editing help @akmozo.  I couldn't figure out how to make that work.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is more methodical.

Answer (score 0):

The first one  worked for me with some modification.
I have 3 buttons in single td, with other 4 td have texts. I have to click on specific button based on the one td value (e.g customer_name). Below is working the code.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"//td[contains(text(),'" + customer_name + "')]/following-sibling::td/button[text()='Accept']"
).click()
```